# How to implement a python mail server with ESMTP which understands EHLO

Tags: python, smtp

I need a python library to implement a ESMTP server in python. Just like a SMTP server, I want to use it to receive emails, but which is capable of handling the EHLO protocol.

After some googling I did not found something useful, and ESMTP does not seem to be part of any standard library. Therefore any direct help is welcome.

Thanks,
  Alex

Comment: Start with the RFCs. Go from there.

Comment: RFC is not python. I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I was asking for a python implementation/library I can use in the same/similar way as python's SMTP. Only people should answer which know that there is such a module or which know for sure there isn't.

Comment: Writing a SMTP server is **HARD**, regardless of how you start. There are no shortcuts other than to not write one.

Comment: A client which does not fall back to plain SMTP if ESMTP is not advertised is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/), if it does not 100% suit your needs, it probably is much a better staring point than, well, scratch.

Comment: lamson seems to be very extensive, complicated and out of scope. Isn't there a simple pyESMTP implementation which does exactly as SMTP does with the addition of EHLO? This would be the most easy. Otherwise I might bite the bullet and spend hours trying to figure out how to write a simple ESMTP server with lamson. Didn't find any examples of that...